# Don't mark message as acknowledged in reactive Function with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using `spring-cloud-stream` in version Horsham SR1 with Java 13. I am using Google Pub/Sub as underlying messaging system.

I have a reactive `Function` that looks like this:

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<Message>, Mono<Void>> messageConsumer() {
    return messageFlux ->
            messageFlux
                    .flatMap(message -> {
                        // do something
                        return something;
                    })
                    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("could not process  message", throwable))
                    .then();
}
```

How can I get Spring to *not* acknowledge an erroneous message? Is it sufficient to throw an exception inside the `flatMap` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that there are pros and cons with each approach and with reactive  we have no view into the stream. It is completely under your control. In fact one of the main differences is that the above function is only invoked once, where if it was imperative function it would be invoked on each message.

Basically with reactive user effectively declares the unit of operation as the entire stream (whatever that may mean in he context of your application).
With imperative the unit of operation is a single Message, hence we can do things like per-message acks, nacks etc.

Comment: OK, thank you for your comment.
And I guess there isn't something like a wrapper object for messages to mark them as acknowledged. Or am I wrong?

Comment: There can't be since we have to account for all what is possible with reactive API including grouping, aggregating, filtering merging etc. We actually tried with few features and every time we solve one issue we open up another. It's a different mindset which requires different approach. The benefit is you can do much more due to how rich with features reactive API is, but as long as you understand that such list comes at he price.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky isn't there a way to work with something like `Flux<AcknowledgeableMessage>` which enables manual acknowledgments? For example, Spring Cloud GCP provides exactly that, while still retaining an ability to work with underlying `Flux`. 
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.3.0/reference/html/index.html#reactive-stream-subscriber